# How to get Choice Fields Choices in alternative language?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-on-prem, language, resource-files, alternate-language

Is there a way to get Choice Fields choices in **alternative language**?

I have a web site that is in Swedish and alternative language English. I'm using resource files. The field name is translated correctly but the choices aren't.

If I create a web site where the web language is in English the choices are in English.

```
<Field
      ID="{21FC2221-82DB-410E-85A8-9F3B19E63819}"
      Name="InternalName"
      DisplayName="$Resources:R,Field_x_DisplayName"
      Description="$Resources:R,Field_x_Description"
      Type="Choice"
      Required="FALSE"
      Group="$Resources:R,FieldGroup_x_Name">
<CHOICES>
  <CHOICE>$Resources:R,Field_x_Choice_a</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>$Resources:R,Field_x_Choice_b</CHOICE>
  <CHOICE>$Resources:R,Field_x_Choice_c</CHOICE>
</CHOICES>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From microsoft:

Optional Text. Specifies the display text for the choice.

The value can be a reference to a resource in the format $Resources:String. However, choice values are not supported by the multilingual user interface (MUI). Choice values are initialized in the default language of the web site and do not change when a user switches to an alternate language supported by the site.